# How to use tailwind in an external repository? Classes not working

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have about 7 different repos which all have there own tailwind setup (EG 7 different repos with 7 different versions of the same button) so I have created a private repo to remove this duplication but I'm having issues with classes not being applied.

I have an issue were only the classes used in the website are applied to the components. EG My page uses `mr-8`, my button is using `mr-8` and `px-2.5` but the button only has the `mr-8` class applied.

I have this in my purge content:     `'.node-modules/\\@my-name/react-tailwindui/lib/**/*.{ts,tsx}'`

This is an example of my button.

```
<button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center items-center border font-medium 
rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-opacity-30 text-xs p-2.5 border-transparent 
dark:border-gray-500 text-white hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-primary-00 bg-primary-600 
shadow-sm rounded-full mr-8">Sign in</button>
```

These are the classes applied

[image: Example of classes applied]

Thanks
Kurtis

Answer (score 0):

Check your tailwindcss version, `p-2.5` only exists in v2.x

Comment: I doubled checked anyway but the classes work if I put them into the site I'm building, the issue is when the classes are in the internal repo only and not any of the pages. Thanks.